# turn database into parsed json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

so i have a table full of events. my controller call looks like this

```
 @gig = Gigtable.where(eventurl: (params[:gigurl])).all
 @gigjson = @gig.to_json
```

Im not sure if im doing this correctly. I have an ajax call. I'm wanting the to json (which should be each row in its own set of `{}` hopefully to be pulled into the ajax controller only if the `eventid` has a url from the `event table` called gigurl (its not being passed through yet. im not sure how to do that either).

The `@gigjson` is passing all the database back as json (checked with byebug).

Basically i need gigurl to be passed from the view to the controller. (everything else works that way. my other table has the id of the url passed into the ajax like this

`'' + link + 'data'`

i'd like to have it so something like this was achieveible

the urlcall would be(in ajax)

`'' + gigjson + 'the controller method here?'

thats all the code i have so far. Nothing in routes, Nothing in the ajax just a standard ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to:

1. Define a route;
2. Render the data in JSON from the controller.

For step 1, assuming your AJAX call uses GET, you can add this to your `routes.rb` file:

```
get 'gigjson/:gigurl', to: 'your_controller#your_action', defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

I have defined JSON as default format to make things simpler, so you don't need to change your JS call. For step 2, in your controller, you can rewrite your action as follows (I have removed non useful instance variables):

```
render :json, Gigtable.where(eventurl: (params[:gigurl]))
```

You don't need to add `.all`, you are already specifying a `where` clause.

At this point you can use the URL `http://your_server.com/gigjson/GIGURL`, replacing `GIGURL` with the parameter you need.

Comment: Hey taglia, Thanks for this, The GIGURL, how will this be passed through? Thats one of the things im confused at. Is it the part in the ajax where the url call will be the `'/gigjson' + GIGURL` as it changes depending on the pages its on

Comment: I don't understand your question. GIGURL will be passed as a parameter in the request. So if you call 'http://server.com/gigjson/whatever123', `params[:gigurl]` will be equal to 'whatever123'. If you prefer, you can also remove the `:gigurl` from the route, and call the URL 'gigjson?gigurl=whatever123'. No changes in the controller.